# Including selectors in url when changing background-image

Tags: jquery

I have a self-invoking function that should run when the page loads. It should run through all "projectContainer" divs, and change their background-image css property to portfolio/*name attribute of current projectContainer*/front.jpg . However, I'm being given a syntax error on the line of the function to do that, and can't seem to resolve it. Any ideas?

```
(function(){
   $(".projectContainer").css('background-image', 'url("'/portfolio/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/front.jpg'")');
})();
```

Comment: You have a mess with the quotes. Please review that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors with how you try to concatenate the string, plus the fact that you need to use some sort of iteration in order to access the `this` of each element.

Try using the [function syntax of the `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) method

```
(function(){
   $(".projectContainer").css('background-image', function(){
      return 'url("/portfolio/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/front.jpg")';
   });
})();
```

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a function parameter for .css, that's extremely useful, thank you :). This may be a stupid question, but how could I go about dealing with the url when $(this).attr('name') includes spaces in the filename? The obvious answer would be to remove spaces in the name attribute, but that's not an option. I could remove spaces from the filename, but can I make $(this).attr('name') return without spaces?

Comment: if you remove the spaces will the file be found ?

Comment: Say for example the name attribute is "Project 1". I need the name to have the spaces because in the project container, the words "Project 1" will be visible. However, when looking for the image file as above, "Project 1" is changed to "Project%201", which I cannot name the file because of the percent symbol. I could name the file as "Project1", however. Is there a way to remove the spaces from what $(this).attr('name') returns, therefore returning "Project1"?

Comment: Ah, I've solved my own problem actually, by amending $(this).attr('name') with .split(" ").join("")

Comment: the `%20` is translated to a space when used in urls, so if the folder does have a space it will be found. You do not need to add the %20 to the actual folder name

Comment: if you do have to replace you can do `$(this).attr('name').replace(/\s/g,'')`